# Text to csv format with unstructured space in python

Tags: python

Convert unstructured header text and below data to csv format .

Header is having multiple space in between for which i am not able to split below data

Input [Input Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYz7w.png)

OutpuT snap [Oput snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3owGf.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataset?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. You haven't asked a question and this isn't a help center, tutorial or discussion forum.

Comment: Updated my dataset as image for better reference

Answer (score 1):

There is a csv module in Python to manipulate csv files, but you can also use the pandas module that is designed for this as well.

Let's say the following code is the dataframe you're trying to convert into a csv file :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': [1, 2], 'Col_2': [3, 4], 'Col_3': [5, 6]})
```

Which gives you this :

```
   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
0     1      3      5
1     2      4      6
```

When you want to write it in a csv file, you have to use this command :

`df.to_csv('your_file.csv', sep=',' index=False)`

And if the separator in your header is a space, then you should indicate in the arguments :

`df.to_csv('your_file.csv', sep=' ' index=False)`

Caution, it will write 'your_file.csv' in your current working directory, unless you use an absolute path.

Comment: Add my input sample and output sample , tried above input but problem is input is not structured.

Comment: Can you precise your question ? For instance :
- are you the one creating the input dataframe ?
- what do you mean by "not structured" ?

Comment: Update the initial query with input format and output format expected

Answer (score 0):

`yourstring.split()` will automatically split strings into a list no matter how many spaces are used. Then you can use that list as a header.